# EntityFieldQuery gives error on adding propertyCondition

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, database

I have to list down taxonomy term ids which should be greater than a specific tid.
Below is the code I am using:-

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$tid = variable_get('last_player_update'); //last index of player update

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition( 'tid',  'value', $tid, '>=')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', 3)
  ->propertyOrderBy('tid', 'ASC')
  ->range(0, 1000); 

$result = $query->execute();
```

On executing the script I am getting the following error:-

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '9174 'value') AND (taxonomy_term_data.vid = '3') ORDER BY taxonomy_term_data.ti' at line 1: SELECT taxonomy_term_data.tid AS entity_id, :entity_type AS entity_type, NULL AS revision_id FROM {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data WHERE (taxonomy_term_data.tid 9174 :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (taxonomy_term_data.vid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ORDER BY taxonomy_term_data.tid ASC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => value [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 3 [:entity_type] => taxonomy_term ) in EntityFieldQuery->execute()
```

What I am missing in the above code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Fields* have columns. Properties do not. You want:

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition( 'tid',  $tid, '>=')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', 3)
  ->propertyOrderBy('tid', 'ASC')
  ->range(0, 1000);
```